# Wrong answer from S.min when strings used

Tags: sanctuary

```
S.min ('1') ('02') =>'02'
```

Why is this even possible? (yes type coercion... but this is Sanctuary)
Can Sanctuary be configured so that Nothing is returned when Strings are used?
Is there an elegant way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the type of [`S.min`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#min):

```hs
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

`String` satisfies the requirements of Ord, so `String -> String -> String` is one possible specialization:

```js
> S.min ('foo') ('bar')
'bar'
```

If you are dealing with inputs that *should* be numbers but may not be, the best approach is to deal with the uncertainty up front:

```js
//    untrustedInput1 :: Any
//    untrustedInput2 :: Any

//    input1 :: Maybe Number
const input1 = S.filter (S.is ($.Number)) (S.Just (untrustedInput1));

//    input2 :: Maybe Number
const input2 = S.filter (S.is ($.Number)) (S.Just (untrustedInput2));
```

Then, you could use [`S.lift2`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#lift2) to transform `S.min` into a function that can operate on `Maybe Number` values:

```hs
S.lift2 (S.min) :: (Apply f, Ord a) => f a -> f a -> f a
```

The signature above can be specialized like so:

```hs
S.lift2 (S.min) :: Maybe Number -> Maybe Number -> Maybe Number
```

The final step is to apply `S.lift2 (S.min)` to the trusted inputs:

```js
S.lift2 (S.min) (input1) (input2)
```

Here is a full working example:

```js
> S.lift2 (S.min)
.         (S.filter (S.is ($.Number)) (S.Just ('1')))
.         (S.filter (S.is ($.Number)) (S.Just ('02')))
Nothing
```